can a js URL object be a long number?
new URL(`http://12345678901`) is not valid but new URL(`http://1234567890`) and new URL(`http://a12345678901`) are.
these work:


console.log(new URL(`http://1234567890`))
console.log(new URL(`http://a12345678901`))



This does not:


console.log(new URL(`http://12345678901`))



Here's the error in chrome:

VM2064:1 Uncaught TypeError: Failed to construct 'URL': Invalid URL at :1:1 (anonymous) @   VM2064:1

Firefox:

Uncaught TypeError: URL constructor: http://12345678901 is not a valid URL.
 debugger eval code:1
debugger eval code:1:1
 debugger eval code:1

I expect the url to work. I tried reading https://url.spec.whatwg.org/#concept-basic-url-parser but it's very dense and I don't really understand it. These error don't seem like normal js errors, so I guess these are bugs?

1234567890 => 0x499602D2 => 0x49, 0x96, 0x02, 0xD2 => 73, 150, 2, 210 => 73.150.2.210. Meanwhile 12345678901 cannot be expressed in 4 bytes.

@Nickistired thanks for that insight. I guess the next question is: is this behavior expected? Obviously the error is not great, but is it part of the URL spec?

That, I do not know, which is why I posted a comment rather than an answer, just an observation :-)

This is not a bug, it's the spec. When the "hostname" part of a URL is a number, then it must be a valid IPv4 address, i.e. a 32-bit number. Separating the bytes with dots (as IPv4 addresses are usually spelled) is optional in URLs.
Hence:
new URL("http://4294967296/") throws due to Invalid URL.
new URL("http://4294967295/") works, and is the same as new URL("http://255.255.255.255/").
The path through the spec is:
https://url.spec.whatwg.org/#hostname-state (step 3.3)
→ https://url.spec.whatwg.org/#concept-host-parser (step 8)
→ https://url.spec.whatwg.org/#concept-ipv4-parser (step 8)

Thanks! Still a weird error message my chrome ("at :1:1 (anonymous) @ VM2064:1"), but at least it is in the spec.

nevermind, its actually a regular error.

I tried this: console.log(new URL(http://12345678901234567890:5000)) and it worked without problems. Also I tried the other two options and it works the same, without any problems

That is strange. Here's a screenshot of the error on chrome: https://imgur.com/a/jxTPhbN. If you don't mind, what system are you running?

I'm running macOS, but now that I'm reading about this I saw that the error may be the domain name

Is it possible to turn your answer into a comment then if you changed your mind on it? Also, I just tested on Safari and I get an strange error there too. I think you are missing quotes in the url of your test actually
